# autoposting to Twitter and Facebook using PHP?

Tags: php, json, api, facebook, twitter

When a user on my system posts something on my website and they can autopost it to their social networks like Facebook and Twitter. How can I approach such a problem in php? I know I have to access their api's and then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but you have to log into twitter or facebook. You need oauth to connect to the twitter services. You can find libraries to achieve this on [dev.twitter.com](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#php)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a WordPress blog you can install one out of many plugins.

You access the API by placing the Application key in the plugin settings.

For API key you need to register a facebook application.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for update/status in twitter:

```
$body = array(
    'status'=>'YOURMESSAGE'
);
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
$oauth_access_token = "YOURVALUE";
$oauth_access_token_secret = "YOURVALUE";
$consumer_key = "YOURVALUE";
$consumer_secret = "YOURVALUE";

$oauth = array( 'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
    'oauth_nonce' => time(),
    'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
    'oauth_token' => $oauth_access_token,
    'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
    'oauth_version' => '1.0');

$base_info = buildBaseString($url, 'POST', $oauth);
$composite_key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($oauth_access_token_secret);
$oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
$oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;
$header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:');
$options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $body,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

$feed = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
$json = curl_exec($feed);
curl_close($feed);

$result_data = json_decode($json);

function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params) {
$r = array();
ksort($params);
foreach($params as $key=>$value){
    $r[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value);
}
return $method."&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $r));
}

function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth) {
$r = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
$values = array();
foreach($oauth as $key=>$value)
    $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\"";
$r .= implode(', ', $values);
return $r;
}
```

And here on Facebook:

```
$Body = array(
        'access_token' => 'YOURVALUE',
        'message'=>'YOURMESSAGE',
        'link'=>'YOURLINK'
    );


    $headers = array
    (
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/feed' );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $Body ) );
    curl_exec($ch );
    curl_close( $ch );
```